# unable to load client cert: -8018 (sec_error_unknown_pkcs11_error Laravel DigitalOcean Centos7

Tags: laravel, centos7

I am using third party cert.pem file to connect their server in Laravel. In my local machine it is working fine and on digital ocean droplet with centos 7 it is giving error

```
unable to load client cert: -8018 (sec_error_unknown_pkcs11_error
```

tried with direct full path and check file exists

Answer (score 1):

After contacting server support, came to know that Centos 7 has a problem with loading client certificate file. We have tried in Rocky Linux and works just fine.